# Why are some Python package names different than their import name?

Tags: python, pip, python-sphinx, pyyaml, qtpy

Some packages are imported with a string which is different from the name of the package on PyPI, e.g.:

```
$ pip list | grep -i "yaml\|qt"  
PyYAML      3.13               
QtPy        1.5.2
```

- pyyaml (pip instal pyyaml), but import yaml
- qtpy (pip install qtpy), yes import is qtpy but package is QtPy

Several tools can't not handle that, e.g sphinx:

```
$ make html
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'wireshark' from module 'logcollector.plugins'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'qtpy'
```

I don't remember it right now, but same is for tools which scan the `requirements.txt` file and print warnings that the `yaml` package isn't installed (but it is and its name is pyyaml).

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple reasons why authors choose to use different names in different environments:

- **Drop-in replacements**: Sometimes it is helpful when you can install a fork and keep the rest of your code the same. I guess the most famous example is [pyyaml](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/) / yaml. I did it when I created [`propy3`](https://pypi.org/project/propy3/) which can be used as a drop-in replacement for `propy`. I would say that this is also what happened with [`pillow`](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/).
- **Convenience**: [`beautifulsoup4`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) can be imported as `bs4` (+ package parking for [`bs4`](https://pypi.org/project/bs4/))
- **Lost credentials**: I don't know of an example where the import name was changed as well, but I think for [`flask-restx`](https://pypi.org/project/flask-restx/) the package name and the import name were changed.

### A word of caution

As [Ziyad Edher has pointed out](https://twitter.com/ziyadedher/status/1254538693949501442) in [a related discussion](https://twitter.com/fchollet/status/1254534893503053825), typosquatting is an issue on PyPI ([source](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3487701/snake-bites-beware-malicious-python-libraries.html)). If you add packages with different names, this gets more likely.

### Other examples

Name in the docs vs "import" package name vs [pypi package name](https://pypi.org/) vs [anaconda packages](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/repo) vs [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/index):

- [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) vs sklearn vs [scikit-learn](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/) vs [scikit-learn](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/scikit-learn) vs [python-sklearn and python3-sklearn](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=buster&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=sklearn)
- [OpenCV-Pyton](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html) vs cv2 vs [opencv-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) vs [py-opencv](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/py-opencv) vs [python-opencv](https://packages.debian.org/buster/python-opencv)
- [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/tutorials.html) vs tables vs [tables](https://pypi.org/project/tables/) vs [pytables](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pytables) vs [python-tables](https://packages.debian.org/buster/python-tables)

Answer (score 8):

Because these two concepts are not really related.
One is a python concept of package/module names, the other one a package manager concept.

Look at a simple packaging command with zip:

```
zip -r MyCoolTool.zip tool.py
```

The Tool is named `tool`, which probably is not unique and if you do not know that its MyCoolTool you do not know which `tool` it is. When I upload it somewhere I name it `MyCoolTool`, so you now a more unique name, that may be a bit more descriptive.

The other point is, that a pip package may include more modules than just one. `PyYAML` could for example include a second python module `yaml2xml` in addtion to `yaml`.

Finally there can be several implementations. `PyYAML` sounds like a pure python implementation. Now assume you need a really fast parser, then you may program `CYAML` with a C-backend, but the same interface at the name `yaml`.

Answer (score 0):

In case of sphinx you can mock 3rd party packages with: [autodoc_mock_imports](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_mock_imports)