# Getting error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework_sso'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am following https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-sso/ tutorial for sso authentication in django, In first step they added 'rest_framework_sso' in INSTALLED_APPSin settings.py without installing any such liberary. When I tried to do the same I got:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework_sso'
```

Then I tried pip/pip3 install 'rest_framework_sso' but I got:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rest_framework_sso (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for rest_framework_sso
```

Then I installed django rest framework but it is stil not working.

I want to know why is it not working and how can I solve this, I didn't found anything that can help me related to this.

Comment: `pip install djangorestframework-sso` (as stated on the pypi.org page) should do the trick

Comment: @He3lixxx it is working Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(For the wiki-aspect, I'll write down a proper answer in case someone comes by the question later)

We have to differentiate between two things here: The name of the package on Pypi, which is what you have to use with `pip`, and the name of the python module that is provided in that package.

For the django rest framework SSO package, the Pypi package name currently is `djangorestframework-sso`, so that has to be used with pip

```sh
pip install djangorestframework-sso
```

However, the python module that this allows you to use is named `rest_framework_sso`, so when adding this to the `INSTALLED_APPS` or using it in any other way in python, you need to use this name, as demonstrated in the documentation:

```py
from rest_framework_sso.views import obtain_session_token
# go on to use obtain_session_token
```

If you wonder, there is a [questions about why this is the case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54886143/12345551)