# python import yaml - but which one?

Tags: python, yaml, python-import

Ok, so you clone a repo, there's an import

`import yaml`

ok, so you do `pip install yaml` and you get:

**`ERROR: No matching distribution found for yaml`**

Ok, so you look for a package with `yaml` in it, and there's like a gazillion of them... usually adding `py` in front does the job, but...

How on earth should I know which one was used?!

And it's not just `yaml`, oh no... there's:

`import cv2 # python-opencv`

`import PIL # Pillow`

and the list goes on and on...

How can I know which import uses which package? Shouldn't there be a PEP for this? Or a naming convention, e.g. import is always the same as the package name?

There's a similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886143/why-are-some-python-package-names-different-than-their-import-name), if you're not frustrated enough :)

Comment: If your question is the same as the one you linked, why duplicate it ? Plus there is no answer SO will be able to provide you. If you've clone a repo it likely has a [`requirements.txt` file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/) or other which points to the packages it need, otherwise, you can only guess.

Comment: `pip install PyYAML`. There is no convention. For opencv, there are multiple language bindings but all import cv2

Comment: Your question would be much more readable, and shorter by a few OKs and so-s, if you described what you did (`I cloned a repo`) instead of writing down as you might talk to someone.

Comment: for OpenCV, there are _official_ packages. only use those. the import being called `cv2` is a historical accident. the package named `opencv-python` is probably due to other names already having been "squatted".

Comment: I accidentally found a duplicate a couple weeks later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [When I clone a repo,] How can I know which import uses which package?

In short: it is the cloned code's responsibility to explain this, and it is an expected courtesy that the cloned code includes an installer that will take care of it.

If this is just some random person's bundle of `.py` files on GitHub with no installation instructions, look for notes in the associated documentation; failing that, make an issue on the tracker. (Or just give up. Maybe look for a better-engineered project that does the same thing.)

However, most "serious", contemporary Python projects are meant to be installed by using some form of packaging system. These have evolved over the years, and best practices have changed many times; but generally speaking, a properly "packaged" and "distributed" project will have either a `setup.py` or (newer; better in many ways, but not universally adopted yet) `pyproject.toml` file at the top level.

A `pyproject.toml` file is a config file in [TOML](https://toml.io/en/) format that simply describes a bunch of project metadata. This requires a build backend conforming to [PEP 517](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/). For a while, this required third-party tools, such as Poetry; but the standard `setuptools` can handle this since version 40.8.0. (As of this writing, the current release is 65.7.0.)

A `setup.py` script is executable code that `pip` will invoke after downloading a package from PyPI (or another package index). Generally, this script will use either `setuptools` or `distutils` (the predecessor to `setuptools`; it has finally been officially [deprecated in 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#distutils-deprecated), and [will be removed in 3.12](https://docs.python.org/3/library/distutils.html#module-distutils)) to install the project, by calling a function named `setup` and passing it a big dict with some project metadata.

**Security warning**: this file is still executable code. It is arbitrary code, and it doesn't have to be following the standard conventions. Also, the package that is actually downloaded from PyPI doesn't necessarily match the project's source shown on GitHub (or another Git provisioning website), if such is even available. (This problem also affects package managers in other languages and ecosystems, notably [npm for Javascript](https://medium.com/hackernoon/im-harvesting-credit-card-numbers-and-passwords-from-your-site-here-s-how-9a8cb347c5b5).)

With the `setup.py` based approach, package dependencies are specified using a  keyword argument to the `setup` function. The specification has changed many times; currently, projects still using a `setup.py` should use the [`install_requires`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#declaring-dependencies) keyword argument.

With the `pyproject.toml` based approach, using `setuptools`' backend, dependencies will be an array (using JSON terminology, as TOML is a superset) stored under `project.dependencies`. This will vary for other backends; for example, Poetry expects this information under `tool.poetry.dependencies`.

In any event, `pip freeze` will output a list of what's installed in the current environment. It's a somewhat common practice for developers to test the code in a virtual environment where the dependencies are installed, dump this output to a `requirements.txt` file, and include that as documentation.

> [When I want to use a third-party library in my own code,] How can I know which import uses which package?

It's worth considering the question the other way around, too: given that we have installed OpenCV for Python using `pip install opencv-python`, and want to use it in our own code, how do we know to `import cv2` specifically?

The answer: there is no convention, and certainly no requirement for the installed package name to match the PyPI name, nor the GitHub etc. repository name. **Read the documentation**. Everyone who intends for their code to be used as a library, will be more than willing to show how, on at least a basic level.

Answer (score 1):

Watch for requirements.txt . Big projects usually have it. You can import packages from this file. Else just google.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Any package on PyPI or cloned from some online repository is free to set itself up with a base directory name it chooses. That base directory `xyz` determines the `import xyz` line. Additionally a package name on PyPI doesn't have to match the repository name where its source code revisions are kept (assuming there is any).

This has the disadvantage that there is no one-to-one relation between package name, repo and/or import-line. But the advantage is that you e.g. can install Pillow, which is backwards compatible with PIL and still use `import PIL` instead of changing all your sources to use `import Pillow as PIL`.

If the repo you clone has a `requirements.txt` look there, you can also look in the `setup.py` for `extra_require`. But there is no guarantee that these are available, or contain the names of the packages to install (e.g. I use a generic `setup.py` that reads its info from a datastructure in the `__init__.py` file when creating/installing a package).

`yaml` seems to be a reserved name on PyPI (at least when I tried to upload a package with that name a few years ago). So that might be the reason the package is named PyYAML, although the Py is not very informative as the python code will not function in another programming language. PyPI' search is not very helpful as it relevance ordering is not relevant (at least not for yaml).

PyPI has no entry in the metadata for the `import line`, but you could extract that from .whl package file as the import line is the top level directory that doesn't match `.dist-info`. This is normally not possible from a .tar.gz` package file. I don't know of any site that does this kind of automatic scraping.

You can click through the packages on PyPI, after searching the import term, and hope you find something that matches the import in the documentation, but that is no guarantee you get the right one.

You might be best of searching for `import yaml` here on stackoverflow, and hope that the question or the answer mentions the package name.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that it might not be a pip package.
Probably what is happening is that the main script is trying to import a secondary script (`yaml.py`, in this case) with functions or utils for the main script to use.

Check if the repo contains a file named `yaml.py`. If it's the case make sure to run the main script while the `yaml.py` is in the same directory.

Also, check for a `requirements.txt` file.
You can install all the requirements inside the file running in shell this line:

```bash
pip install -r *path to your requirements.txt*
```

Hope that this helps.

Comment: "Check if the repo contains a file named yaml.py. If it's the case make sure to run the main script while the yaml.py is in the same directory." This is not a plausible failure mode, because OP described *cloning* the repository - not randomly copying out one or two `.py` files.

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your help and ideas. Big thanks to [Karl Knechter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75118416/9507271) for his exhaustive answer.

tl;dr: I think using some sort of "package" / "distribution" as a standard, would make everyone's lives easier.

However, my question was half-theoretical, to point out something I'd call, an incoherence in Python. You are of course right, there should be `setuptools` or `requirements.txt` or at least some documentation. But, if there isn't any, we're prone to error or additional browsing.

[GospelBG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75118281/9507271) pointed out something important. There could be a script `yaml.py` in the main folder and we need to check and/or guess.

Most importantly, naming imports differently than packages is just plainly misleading. There should be a naming convention or a PEP for this. Again, you can of course eventually get the proper package etc., but it's not explicit and obvious, and it should be! Because in programming, we like it that way, don't we?

I'm no seasoned dev in `Python` and I'm learning `C++`, but e.g. in `C++`, you import a header file with a particular name and static or dynamic libraries by their filename. Now I know this is very "step-by-step, on foot method", but at least you use the exact filenames.

On the upper level you have `CMake`, which would be an equivalent of `setuptools` where using `find_package` or `find_library` you can import package / library. To be honest, I'm not sure if all packages have the exact equivalent name, but at least the ones I used, did match.

Thanks again for your help and answers! I'm open for discussion and comments :)