# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pyjanitor despite pyjanitor being installed

Tags: python, pyjanitor

I've confirmed the pyjanitor package is installed - it shows up in `pip list` and I get a confirmation if I try to reinstall with `pip install pyjanitor`.  But then when I run `import pyjanitor` I get the error:

> No module named 'pyjanitor'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package name is `pyjanitor` but it is imported as janitor:

```
import janitor
```

This is a case of this phenomenon: [Why are some Python package names different than their import name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886143/why-are-some-python-package-names-different-than-their-import-name)